# Dynamic views depending on how many views are present with free form movement

Tags: swift, reactjs, react-native, game-engine, game-physics

I wasn't sure how to word this so bear with me :p

Here is a screenshot of an idea I want to implement but I'm not sure how best to approach it or ever describe it.

[image]

I can do it in either React Native or native iOS so ideas in either realm would be great.

The idea is when there is only one person in the room your video would be a bit bigger and as people join they would scale properly for the phone and be placed in a fun layout (doesn't have to be exactly as shown, just the idea is they scale to take up the best space possible depending on device size and how many people are in the room)

I'm thinking some sort of game engine would be useful for this but not sure. If you could throw out some search terms I could use to approach it it would be great.

I also might want them to be draggable/resizable but I can do that later but the idea is that they are more freeform movements within a certain container size.

Answer (score 0):

This is basic grid functionality, you just have to create styling use cases for each sizing option, and dynamically change the classes based on the number of people in the chatroom... in a really basic form:

```
.6-user-layout {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
}
.4-user-layout {...}
.2-user-layout {...}
```

As your basic styling ^ then simply swap your classes out dynamically:

```
const sizingClass = \`${userCount}-user-layout\`;

return (
    <YourVideo classNames={sizingClass} />
);
```

Unless you are looking for some really specific methods, this is a simple way to do it with React regardless of Browser or Mobile :)

The same goes for any game engine, just define your styling requirements for each number of users or create a simple equation to figure it out, whilst tracking the active users.